# Kill the process currently using a sqlite3 db

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

i need a way to retrieve the name of the process that is currently using my sqlite3 db to kill it with `TerminateProcess()` and unlock the db to perform further query.
I'm using VC++.
There's a way around this?

Comment: I'm assuming Windows since you mention TerminateProcess() which would make this more of a win32 question. You may want to state why you want to kill it in the first place -- it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to corrupt your database.

Comment: Reading on the internet the only way to use a sqlite3 db when it's locked is to kill the process that lock it. That's the reason